# update statement with self join

Tags: t-sql, join, update, sybase

I needed to copy information from one row of a table to another.
I noticed I could do the following:

```
update address
set col1 = a2.col1,
col2 = a2.col2,
.....etc
from address a1, address a2
where a1.id = @to and a2.id = @from
```

However, the above SQL seems kind of ambiguous. 
How do I know it's going to update row @to with data of @from and not the otherway around?

Edit: Note: while I have not done extensive testing, this query does seem to work as I try it against our development database. It simply updates the one @to row with results from the @from row.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to specify a table alias in the first line, instead of just the table name? I would think what's written is a syntax error.

Comment: @JonSeigel, specifying a table alias on the first line produces a syntax error. This does not.

Comment: Eh, I tried. I guess my SQL Server knowledge doesn't apply to Sybase. Different T-SQL I guess.

Comment: Perhaps to be unambiguous, you'll need to prepend the LHS of the SET clause, e.g. `SET a1.col1=a2.col1, a1.col2=a2.col2,...` following the syntax in example 3 [in the manual](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1270/html/iqref/Update.htm)

Comment: @孔夫子, thanks. For some reason I thought that would cause a syntax error. However, for reference, that's not the sybase manual. It's the Sybase IQ manual, which is a different beast. Either way, it does seem to work.

Comment: As an attempt at a guess (I'm not a Sybase expert), which may have been your guess as well, perhaps the first instance is being taken to be the target of the update. If you haven't found that out for sure in the meantime and you'd like to be certain your statement always updates the intended instance, you could use a correlated subquery instead of a join. Don't know whether the former would be less efficient than the latter in Sybase, though.

Comment: @AndriyM, How would you use a subquery to do this?

Comment: As it's a single row & column to update and a single row & column to read from, I would try something like this, probably: `UPDATE address SET col1 = (SELECT col1 FROM address WHERE id = @from) WHERE id = @to;`. And sorry, I was incorrect: the subquery isn't a correlated one (it is not correlated with the main statement's row set, it is just a subquery returning one of the columns from one specific row).

Comment: @AndriyM- However, since it's not a single column (It's many) It really doesn't make sense to use a subquery.

Comment: Oh, how silly of me! You are right of course, using scalar subqueries doesn't make much sense here. Don't know how I was reading the question that I managed to miss that. This one might do better: `UPDATE address SET col1 = a2.col1, col2 = a2.col2, ... FROM address a1, (SELECT * FROM address WHERE id = @from) a2 WHERE a1.id = @to;`. Don't know if Sybase would allow a subquery in that context, though. And certainly the syntax is less elegant than yours, it's just that it might be less ambiguous to the peruser this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be less ambiguous you can prepend the alias in the set clause. (Taken from 孔夫子 in the comments, who did not submit an answer.)

```
update address
set a1.col1 = a2.col1,
a1.col2 = a2.col2,
.....etc
from address a1, address a2
where a1.id = @to and a2.id = @from
```

Comment: wouldn't this have to be

    `update a1 ... `

I am trying to do this in SQL Server where it does. Just curious.

Comment: It should be ```Update a1```